# Using minikube with --driver=docker fails to forward from localhost to minikube internal address

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, service-node-port-range

Edit - this is on OSX
Also, I've tried running `minikube service <service-name>`, that's shown below and when it tries to open it in a browser I get a "connection refused" signal because the port is closed.

I have a kubernetes deployment that works fine when using `--driver=virtualbox`. I translated this to use `--driver=docker` and this almost works except when I do the following

```
$ minikube service websocket-nodeport
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |        NAME        | TARGET PORT |           URL           |
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|-------------------------|
| default   | websocket-nodeport |        9000 | http://172.17.0.4:30007 |
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|-------------------------|
  Starting tunnel for service websocket-nodeport.
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| NAMESPACE |        NAME        | TARGET PORT |          URL           |
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|------------------------|
| default   | websocket-nodeport |             | http://127.0.0.1:62032 |
|-----------|--------------------|-------------|------------------------|
  Opening service default/websocket-nodeport in default browser...
❗  Because you are using a Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.
```

But if I go to

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:62032
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 62032: Connection refused
```

nothing happens, it isn't a valid address. However, if I do the following

```sh
$ minikube ssh
# inside the VM now
docker@minikube:~$ curl http://172.17.0.4:30007
ok!: websocket-frontend-b7c8dc4b9-5jtg6
```

I get the response I want! So this means that my service is running and the URL output of the `websocket-nodeport` address as is internal to minikube is correct but for some reason the local address `http://127.0.0.1:62032` isn't be forwarded to the minikube VM.

How do I get this forward to work?

Comment: operating system?

Comment: Can you please run `minikube service websocket-nodeport` and check?

Comment: i get the same issue on mac

Answer (score 3):

`$ minikube service <service-name>`
this will open up a tunnel to connect to the service, make sure the service is a NodePort service.

If it opens a browser and you get a `404` this is because the url in the address bar doesn't exist within your api. Changing the URL PATH to correct URL paths/routes you defined in your API should fix this

Answer (score 2):

To open exposed service run following

```
$ minikube service <service-name>
```

This command will open the specified service in your default browser.

Comment: I'm confused, that's the crux of the issue. As documented, I run `minikube service websocket-nodeport` and it tries to open the page but it shows 404 and that the connection is refused (i.e. http:127.0.0.1:{{port}} is closed)

Comment: But 404 is different than connection refused. If you ctrl+c then you get nothing. I 'm also having the same issue, I'm trying to understand what's going on. I'm also on mac with docker driver.

Comment: I am running macos 10, $minikube service fleetman-webapp  I get following error:Because you are using Docker driver on darwin, the terminal needs to be open to run it.

Comment: @hoque bro finally i found the solution to my own problem, i was exposing my webapi using service of type NodePort, service port was 31000 but i was unable to get response from 127.0.0.1:31000, but after running `minikube service <service-name>` i got to know about tunnel thing, and my webapi was tunneling through port=55959. Thanks <3

Comment: i guess, you can start the tunnel manually using `minikube tunnel`